# Request Headers not found when sending requests to Heroku PHP API

Tags: php, api, heroku, httprequest

First time Heroku user!

My `php` api has a authentication method for an `iOS` app:

```
public function authenticateAppKey() {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_APP_KEY'])) {
        error('App Key Not Supplied');
        exit;
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_APP_KEY'] != self::$api_key) {
        error('App Key Incorrect');
        exit;
    }
}
```

It is always returning `App Key Not Supplied`

This has always worked up until I have switched to Heroku, wondering if I have missed a setting during the Heroku setup.

These are my build packs:

[image]

I also have https://github.com/travstoll/heroku-buildpack-php installed on the server

Deployment Log if helpful:

```
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/php
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.lock; using PHP ^5.5.17
       - apache (2.4.18)
       - nginx (1.8.1)
       - php (5.6.19)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.0.0-beta1 2016-03-03 15:15:10
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
       NOTICE: No Procfile, using 'web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2'.
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 13M
-----> Launching...
       Released v43
       https://<address>.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Answer (score 3):

OK found the issue and fixed.

It seems that request header variables should not have underscores in them. This has only been highlighted since moving to Heroku.

So in my situation `APP_KEY` was not visible to the code, changed to `APPKEY` and everything was fixed.

Comment: Underscores are not valid in HTTP header names, so Heroku is behaving correctly. You probably also misunderstood the underscores in the array keys - if you send a header "App-Key", PHP translates that to "HTTP_APP_KEY".

Comment: I have had APP_KEY for along time now, on a different server, and had no issues up until Heroku

Comment: Good for you. It's still not legal according to the HTTP specification, and other web servers such as Nginx will drop headers with underscores in their names as well.

Comment: Since it's now fixed with the correct info for others to find in the future, I gave you an up vote :)

Comment: Working for me. :) But It's weird of heroku.

Comment: Glad it sorted you out, annoyed me for a while!